# How to collect data from user on certain condtion once a Workflow is started

Tags: workflow, initiation-form

I have just started with Sharepoint Workflows and am able to create Association and Initiation forms in Visual Studio.

Currently I am working on a Sequential Workflow and have a scenario wherein I need to collect data from a user, once he has approved the list item and based on that data create tasks in the task list for different users.

I am not able to figure out exactly how can I collect this data. It is not initiation data. I have heard about "Collect Data from User" in SharePoint Designer. But dont know of anything similar for Workflows in Visual Studio.

Can someone please guide me as to how can I achieve this. 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, verify that you can't build your workflow in SharePoint designer. I know that's not the answer developers want to hear, but SharePoint designer workflows ultimately involve less pain and frustration. If you can't build it with SharePoint designer, check out Nintex workflows and see if that would work. (Nintex has a high price tag, but it pays for itself pretty quickly in time saved).

But, if you're stuck doing VS based workflows, then assign a custom task. That's what the "collect data from user" is doing. At design time, it creates a custom content type that inherits from "Task" with additional fields added and associates it with the tasks list. At run time, it assigns that task, and waits for it to be completed.

Comment: Hi Mike,
I did try verifying if I could build the workflow in Sharepoint Designer, but was not convinced enough.
However I was able to Create Task With Content Type and could successfully collect data from user.

Thanks Alot for the Help!!

Comment: Also the following Walkthroughs helped me in achieving this task using the applications forms
Part 1 - 
http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-sequential-workflow-with-a-custom-task-form-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1-of-2/

Part 2 -
http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-sequential-workflow-with-a-custom-task-form-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010-part-2-of-2/